# Could i create a question with an answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Asking a question and answering it yourself straight away](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/asking-a-question-and-answering-it-yourself-straight-away)

Could i create a question with an answer i found myself for help other people? This way other TeX users could improve it and/or contribute with different solutions.

Comment: It's ok, though please have a look at [Asking a question and answering it yourself straight away](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4/asking-a-question-and-answering-it-yourself-straight-away).

Comment: @StefanKottwitz: Interesting. Sorry for duplicate the question, i've searched a lot on TeX Meta, but with the wrong terms, i guess.

Comment: No problem :-) I'll close it as a duplicate, pointing to the existing question with answers. You could also post your opinion there, if you like.