# Exposing the subtext

Tags: discussion, answers

It is often the case that the piece of information that one is after is to be found within the "fine print" of an answer. The example that I currently came across with is the following. **How one can add sectioning in `srclttr2` class?**

Googling answers were not straight. The solution was found (BTW, not using goole directly) in [Stefan Kottwitz's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25064/412) answer. However, it is found in the 7th item of his answer.

For those who will encounter the same question in the future I want to some how highlight this part of the answer. So, is the best way to post a new question and answer it immediately, giving credit to the original answer? Or and another comment which will help google to find this answer? What would you suggest?

Comment: Good question, I've been wondering about that as well. I think posting a question and self-answering it with attribution and a link to the other answer is a good idea.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ask a new question that's focused on the thing you've actually been searching for. It seems like it wouldn't be a duplicate because you're actually looking for something else than the question in which you found the relevant information. Having several questions that can be answered similarly, i.e. with the same tools, is fine. Also, asking questions to which you know the answer is fine (see [Asking a question and answering it yourself straight away](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4/4012)), I think there's even a blog post about that by one of the SE overlords.

I don't think we want people highlighting stuff in other people's answers that they think is important. If you think an important aspect of an answer isn't highlighted enough, you can post a comment to the answerer, proposing clarification; but I don't think this is the case here. Answers are only highlighted as a whole, in comparison to other answers: On the one hand by the OP choosing an accepted answer, on the other hand by all users upvoting (and downvoting) answers.

Comment: The blog post is [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) and it's available at the bottom of the questionaire.